# Lagrange interpolation and asymptotic behaviour

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My question is very short. Suppose I'm looking for a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $N$ and I know its values at $x_0,x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{N-1}$, say $p(x_i)=f_i$. And I also know its behaviour for $x\rightarrow\infty$:
$$p(x)=c x^N+O(u^{N-1})$$
where $c$ is a known constant.
Is there a possibility to write down the polynomial by means of Lagrange interpolation? I don't know how to handle the asymptotic condition.

Comment: First, I suspect a typo - it should be $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}$.

Let $q(x) = p(x) - c x^N$.  See what you can say about $q(x)$.

Comment: Ok, I can find q(x) using lagrange interpolation because its degree is $N-1$. The I can find $p(x)=q(x)+c x^N$. If I don't overlook anything, this should solve the problem.